# Using RequireJS to load easyui

Tags: jquery, requirejs, jquery-easyui

I am new to the concept script loaders and I am attempting to load jQuery and easyUI with RequireJS.  I am not sure how to bring in the easyUI after loading the jQuery. Can someone offer a simple explanation of what I need to do?

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "app/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "/app",
      "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min",
      "easyui": "app/lib/jquery-easyui/jquery.easyui.min"
    }
});
define(["jquery"], function($){
    console.log($);

    //Not sure how to link in the easyUI
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have defined `jQuery`, you can just use `require()` to require `easyui`

```
define(["jquery"], function($){        
   require(["easyui"], function () {
     //easyui is now usable
   });
});
```